# Adding an embedded youtube video to a page dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I've looked through the existing posts suggested for this topic, but none seem to address specifically what I'm looking for.

I have a page with numerous embedded youtube videos, and it takes over a minute to load the page with a fast connection - on a slow connection it would take nearly forever.

I have been researching lightbox methods, but most of them require having the object (image, video) already coded into the page and then changing the CSS to make it visible when a link is clicked. What I want to do is hard-code the link (text or image) and the surrounding divs used to create the lightbox effect and then have the code for the embedded video created when the link is clicked on.

Something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="videos.php" onclick="myFunction(*youtube id*); return false;">Video #1</a>
    <div class='lightboxOverlay hidden'>   //div is hidden
        <div class='lightboxContent'>
            // Javascript writes code for embedded video here,
            // then makes the parent div visible
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would use "getElementByID(*div id*).innerHTML="*CodeForVideo*", but there are multiple videos so I wouldn't be able to target just the one that was clicked on.

Is there any way to target the div for whichever video was selected and write the code in that div only, or is there a better way to accomplish this?

---

Thanks for the quick reply, @Davidlrnt! However, the site must remain backward-compatible, and the Youtube API only works with HTML5-compatible browsers.

I tried this:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="videos.php" onclick="vLightbox(Rt87CBUBlCo); return false;"><img src="images/thumbnails/20160828.jpg" /></a>
    <div class='lbOverlay hidden'>
        <div id="Rt87CBUBlCo" class='lbContent'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

function vLightbox(YoutubeID){
    document.getElementById(YoutubeID).innerHTML = '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + youTubeID + '-ZnkxjjymsU?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="float:right; margin-left:20px;"></iframe>';
}
```

and it didn't work. I must be missing something...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the youtube iframe api, and you can dynamically embed any videos by their id.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

`function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }`

Answer (score 1):

OK, digging through this piece by piece, I've come up with an answer that works for me. For the edification of others, I'll post it here:

HTML Markup:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="videos.php" onclick="vLightbox('-ZnkxjjymsU'); return false;"><img src="images/thumbnails/20160828.jpg" /></a>
    <div class='lbOverlay hidden'>
        <div id="-ZnkxjjymsU" class="lbContent">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(-ZnkxjjymsU is the Youtube ID for the video)

Javascript:

```
function vLightbox(YoutubeID){
    document.getElementById(YoutubeID).innerHTML = '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + YoutubeID + '?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="float:right; margin-left:20px;"></iframe>';
}
```

CSS:

```
.lbOverlay{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-image: url("images/overlay.png");
}

.lbContent{
    position: relative;
    top: 15%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}

.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

Still need to toggle the "hidden" class for the "lbOverlay" div and I've got some cosmetic work to do, but that should be easy...